# Why $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^+, *)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Can someone explain to me *why* $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^+, *)$ where $*$ is multiplication.

My book says they aren't really isomorphic and doesn't say why. I thought that they are because of two reasons

> 1. All infinite groups with generator  is isomorphic to  $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$ and clearly  $(\mathbb{R}^+, *)$ is infinite (edit, but no generator, okay)
> 2. The isomorphism is given by $f(x) = e^x$

Comment: Your map is a homomorphism. Why is it not an isomorphism? (This isn't enough, but it is of dire importance that you check your logic). In response to 1., not all infinities are created equal. Any real analysis class should tell you this.

Comment: Not all infinite groups are isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$. For one that would mean that all infinite groups are abelian, which is definitely not true.

Comment: All infinite **cyclic** groups are isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z,+)$. Not every infinite group is cyclic, however.

Comment: @NickD, I misquoted the theorem. There must be a generator for the group to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly, the one I have has no generator.

Comment: You can't even embedded a $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ inside an arbitrary infinite group. For example, $C_{2}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: Ah, well then there's your answer. $\Bbb{R}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Can subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which must also contain the irrational ever have a generator? I believe not, simply because there can never be a generator that generators the irrationals and the other rationals (may or may not be in the group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- All infinite groups are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$? So, what does the classification theorem for abelian groups say about a guy like $\mathbb{Z} \oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$?
- As for your isomorphism: which would be the inverse image of $e^{1/2}$?

Comment: Right, my map is not onto.

Answer (score 10):

Your first claim is false.  In fact, there is not even a bijection between the sets $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{R}^+$, by Cantor's diagonalization argument.

However, the map $x \mapsto e^x$ does provide an isomorphism between the groups $(\Bbb{R}, +)$ and $(\Bbb{R}^+, \times)$.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are good: $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$ is cyclic and countable, while $(\mathbb{R}^+, \times)$ is neither cyclic nor countable.

Here's another, less direct answer: $(\mathbb{R}^+, \times)$ is [divisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), while $(\mathbb{Z}, + )$ is not divisible.